# Elastic search not giving the results even though there is a record

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic search.

I have created one Index, and added a mapping file.

Mapping file content:

```
{
"properties": {
    "funds": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

added one document with _doc/1.

When I search with `{"query" : { "match_all" :{} }}` using postman tool, data is coming.

Where as when I add filter, getting empty results.

```
{  "query" : {
"bool" : {
  "filter" : [
    {
      "term" : {
        "funds.name" : "xyz"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

}
}

Can anyone please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is "xyx" single word or multi word sentence?

Comment: Its a multi word sentence. Ex: General Funds, Fixed Funds, ...

Comment: @Venu, text field is analyzed using standard analyzer by default which breks text on whitspaces, u need to use the match as suggested by Val. so in your case it would be `general` and `funds` tokens for `general funds` text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `match` query instead of a `term` one since `funds.name` is analyzed text (i.e. of type `text`):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {                         <--- change this
            "funds.name": "xyz"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tried with {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {                        
            "funds.name": "xyz"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}. But still getting empty records.

Comment: You still have `term` in your query, not `match`. Can you show a sample document that you expect to be returned?

Comment: Response for match all is this:

Comment: Response for match all is this: {"took":6,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":2,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"myfunds","_type":"type_name","_id":"1","_score":1.0,"_source":{ "funds": { "name": "General Fund", "code": "Gen-001", "description": "General usage of funds" } }},{"_index":"myfunds","_type":"type_name","_id":"2","_score":1.0,"_source":{ "funds": { "name": "Mutual Fund", "code": "Mut-001", "description": "Mutual funds for an employee" } }}]}}

Comment: So if you search with `xyz` it's normal that you don't get anything. Try searching for `general` or `fund`

Comment: Im expecting 'General fund' for for my query. {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": { 
            "funds.name": "General Fund"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: Again, please re-read my answer, you need to change `term` to `match` in order for it to work.

Comment: Thanks @Val, Getting the response.